# Bash program that returns 1 on input and 0 otherwise

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a standard linux terminal program that when given text input (in standard in) returns a 1 and 0 if no text is provided? (The reverse logic would also be fine).

Example

```
echo hello | unknown_program  # returns 1
echo | unknown_program        # returns 0
```

Edit:

My usecase, is for calling a program from a c++-program, that should be agnostic to where on the drive it resides. Thats why i do not prefer to create a script file, but using applications that i would assume exist on any linux (or ubuntu in my case) computer.

This is the c++-code but that is not part of the question.

```cpp
auto isConditionMet = std::system("git status --porcelain | unknown_program");
```

And I got a working answer, so at least I am happy.

Comment: `>` is for redirecting to a file. Did you mean to pipe with `|`?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what counts as "standard linux terminal progarm"? Does `test -z`  counts as "standard linux terminal program" or not (it has a parameter)? `returns 1` You want the "standard linux terminal program" to _print_ 0 or 1, or to exit with 0 or 1 _exit status_?

Comment: Note that `echo` outputs a newline. Should your hypothetical program ignore newlines? What about other whitespace, like `echo " "`?

Comment: `unknown_program </dev/null` is a better way to emulate the no-input case. Or `printf '' | unknown_program`. Because `echo` _does_ create input.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you are correct. I never seems to get everything right. Thanks for the edit, whoever did it.

Comment: @Barmar In my case i would like to ignore spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -q '.'` will do this. `.` matches any character except newline. `grep` returns a `0` static code (success) if there are any matches, and `1` if there are no matches.

```
echo hello | grep -q '.'; echo $? # echoes 0
echo | grep -q '.'; echo $? # echoes 1
```

If you want to ignore lines with just spaces as well, change `.` to `[^ ]`.

Answer (score 3):

With bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    echo "stdin is the TTY, no input has been redirected to me"
    exit 0
fi

# grab all the piped input, may block
input=$(cat)
if [[ -z $input ]]; then
    echo "captured stdin is empty"
    exit 0
fi

echo "I captured ${#input} characters of data"
exit 1
```

If this is saved as `./test_input` and made executable, then:

```sh
$ ./test_input; echo $?
stdin is the TTY, no input has been redirected to me
0

$ ./test_input < /dev/null; echo $?
captured stdin is empty
0

$ echo | ./test_input; echo $?
captured stdin is empty
0

$ ./test_input <<< "hello world"; echo $?
I captured 11 characters of data
1

$ echo foo | ./test_input; echo $?
I captured 3 characters of data
1
```

Note that the shell's command substitution `$(...)` removes all trailing newlines, which is why the `echo | ./test_input` case report no data has been captured.

Comment: As an improvement, instead of `input=$(cat)` which attempts to capture **all** the input (which would block if stdin is a process that does not stop producing output), we could do something like `read -n 1 input` which attempts to read a single character.

Comment: If using bash you could use `read -t0`. `hasInput(){ read -t0;echo $?;}`

Answer (score 0):

Using `wc -w` to count words, and shell arithmetic to check condition and get 0 or 1 to `echo`.

```sh
echo | echo "$(("$(wc -w)" > 0))"                       # echoes 0
echo hello world | echo "$(("$(wc -w)" > 0))" # echoes 1
```